# C# - Add new row to a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to add dynamically rows to a `DataGridView` when I clicked on a button.
I have read many posts about it but all of these have a `DataTable` as `DataSource`. In my case, the `DataSource` is a `List` and the rows are custom objects(Product). See the following code:

```
    List<Product> products = 
    (List<Product>)repository.Session.CreateCriteria<Product>().List<Product>();
    ProductsDataGrid.DataSource = products;
```

`AllowUserToAddRow` is true. So how can I add a row dynamically?

---

As I understand it, based on Nasmi Sabeer's answer I have tried:

```
    private void addProductBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Product> products = (List<Product>) ProductsDataGrid.DataSource;
        products.Add(new Product());
        ProductsDataGrid.DataSource = products;
        ProductsDataGrid.Refresh();   
    }
```

But does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wrap your list around a `BindingSource` like so:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = products;
```

And then set the `DataSource` property of the grid to `bs`.

```
ProductsDataGrid.DataSource = bs;
```

Then update your click handler as

```
private void addProductBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    bs.Add(new Product());
    ....
    ProductsDataGrid.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: This way is less readable but works great. Thank you! =D Just curious, why does not works with the simple `List<Product>`?
BTW, `Refresh()` is not necessary.

Comment: Yeah thats a good question :) If you go through msdn documentation for DataSource property of DataGridView, it can be anything that implements IList interface among others and List<t> surely does that. I can only think of some internal binding issue due to binding to a custom type. The doc goes on to say that preferred way is to bind via BindingSource, as it takes care of most of the binding issues for you.

Comment: @Overflow012 List is not UI aware. You should use either `BindingList` or `ObservableCollection` instead, depending on if you are using WinForms or WPF. BindingSource is the INCORRECT way to do this. BindingSource is for non-memory implementations, such as a via OData.

Answer (score 2):

Use `BindingList`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private IBindingList blist;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Binding
        this.blist = new BindingList<Product>();
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.blist;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add
        this.blist.Add(new Product { Id = 2, Text = "Prodotto 2" });
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a Product to the list first and then call Refresh on DataGridView

Comment: It worked for me, can you be more specific about the error you get